# Angular 2 - module is loaded twice on refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, refresh

I have ab Angular 2 app. Using router-deprecated (as the the new router is currently not documented). Having two basic routes (home and admin). 
If I load the app or do a F5 refresh the current module is loaded twice (you can see that the html file is requested twice and the constructor is also called twice. How can I prevent the app to load the route twice? Changing the route does not cause a "double loading". Only a F5/frist load

```
<html>
<head>
<base href= />
<title>Consyd Time Management</title>
<meta charset=UTF-8>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel=stylesheet href=public/css/styles.css>    
<link rel=stylesheet href=node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css>
<script src=node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js></script>
<script src=node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js></script>
<script src=node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js></script>
<script src=public/scripts/externalLibs.js></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id=main class=container-fluid> <start-page>Loading...</start-page>       </div>
```

start.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from     '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { NavigationMenu } from "./navigation";
import { myRoutes } from '../routes';


@Component({
selector: 'start-page',
template: `
<h2>Startseite</h2>
<navigation-menu></navigation-menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavigationMenu]
})
@RouteConfig(myRoutes)

export class StartPage {

}
```

and routes.ts

```
import { RouteDefinition } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { HomePage } from './views/home';
import { AdminPage} from './views/adminpage';


export const myRoutes: RouteDefinition[] = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: HomePage
    },
    {
        path: '/admin',
        name: 'Admin',
        component: AdminPage

    }
];
```

home.ts

```
//imports going here
@Component({
    selector: 'start-page',
    templateUrl: 'public/app/html/home.html',
    directives: [DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [HttpService]
})

export class HomePage {
    constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
        if (!this.selectedProject) {
            this.selectedProject = new Project("Projekt auswählen");
        }
        this.getUsers(this.setUser);

    }
//REST OF CODE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed: Have added externallibs.js twice in index.html (one by hand and one by webpack)....

Comment: Thanks for the idea - I added the the component to the bootstrap array in the NgModules which was causing the double-load. It should have only been in the declarations and not also in the bootstrap.